# Fast random seek on multiple objects

Tags: java, python, avro, random-access

I am currently using avro files for storing data record in files with a size of up to 50GB. The problem is that besides sequentially analysing the files i have to perform random seek on the data. The problem with avro is that i can only seek to certain sync points and and have to iterate across the block until i find the record i look for but this leads to significant performance penalties under some circumstances.
My question now is: Is there a way to store the data in a different format that supports random seek for single records without too much afford.

Restrictions:

- Has to be put on disk (RAM in several use cases too small)
- Needs to be binary
- Programming languages: Python, Java, C++ would be optional but nice to have

Cheers and thanks

Comment: If your data is structured and too heavy, you may try `Apache Hadoop` (distributions [http://hortonworks.com/](http://hortonworks.com/), [http://www.cloudera.com/content/www/en-us.html](http://www.cloudera.com/content/www/en-us.html))` and query your file as table with `Hive, Impala, Spark-stream` etc...

Comment: It depends what kind of seeks you perform. Are they for simple keys (e.g. an integer ID) or more complex? Would a single index be enough or do you perform different types of seeks per file?

Comment: Simple key are sufficient (mainly integer and double, rarely Strings). @Valijon: Thanks for the suggestion the idea is pretty cool, the problem is that the schema i use is a bit more complex than the examples i found, could this might be a problem?

Comment: @M.Die - you could take a look at PalDB then (https://github.com/linkedin/PalDB).

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Chronicle Map](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map). This implement an off heap ConcurrentMap which gives you random access based on key. You can use it in memory, partially on disk, using shared memory with one copy across multiple JVMs and optionally replicated it across multiple machines.

Disclaimer: I helped architect this solution.